# how to copy file/folder and preserve their creation date on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer, file-management, copy-paste

When I ran out of storage I brought a new Hard disk and of course I needed to copy all my data from my old hard disk to the new one.

when I tried to manage the copied files over the new hard disk I lost all the creation dates of all my files and folders, now I am lost in a bunch of files and folders where I can't remember when I them and of course I lost the way I can sort it by creation date. All the creation dates were  set to the new creation date when I copied them.

I wonder if there is a way to copy files and folders and preserve the creation date?

For the already copied files and folder is there any chance to change their creation date in a batch mode?

Comment: How did you copy the files?

Comment: just copy/cut and paste

Comment: You said, "..I lost the way I can sort it by creation date". I see that ModifiedDate is preserved for all the files and some of the folders. Given this, you could sort it based on the ModifiedDate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows works like this :

- When you **move** a file to a different folder then its creation date will not change.
- When you **copy** a file do a different folder then its creation date will change.

The difference is because when you copy a file on your computer,
a new file is created with a new timestamp.

To copy and keep creation date is possible using the Windows utility of
[robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).
Its syntax is rather simple, executed in a Command Prompt (CMD) :

```
robocopy source-path target-path
```

You should remove your previously copies files before executing `robocopy`.

For more information with screenshots, see for example the article
[How to Copy Files without Changing Date Stamp on Windows 10](https://www.jiho.com/en/tips/copy-files-without-changing-date-stamp.html).

Comment: Good answer. I can only add an example of command for copying directory (and its content) with all dates and attributes: `robocopy "C:\your folder" "F:\your folder" /e /dcopy:DAT /MT`. All arguments described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: @Kyo Your link is for Windows Server, not Windows 10, which doesn't have /dcopy or /MT options. Since /COPY:DAT is the default, all you need is /e (which should be added to this answer).

Comment: on my Win10 Pro `robocopy /?` lists both `MT` and `dcopy`, and the command works fine

Comment: To copy a single file, use this command `robocopy "C:\my folder" "D:\my folder" "file name.jpg"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a utility or tool that supports this feature. One such free tool is Robocopy, which is a built-in command-line tool in Windows. It has a switch (/DCOPY:T) that allows you to preserve the original timestamps, including creation time, when copying files and folders.

To use Robocopy, you can open a Command Prompt window and type the following command:

robocopy source_folder destination_folder /E /DCOPY:T

Replace "source_folder" with the path to the folder you want to copy and "destination_folder" with the path to the destination folder. The /E switch will copy all subfolders, and the /DCOPY:T switch will preserve the timestamps.

Another 2 tools that allow you to preserve the original timestamps, including creation time, when copying files and folders, Teracopy and Gs Richcopy, both are GUI tools, also easy and quick .

As for changing the creation date of already copied files and folders in batch mode, you can use a file manager or a command-line tool that supports this feature. For example, you can use a tool called BulkFileChanger from NirSoft. It allows you to modify the creation time, last access time, and last modified time of multiple files and folders at once.

To use BulkFileChanger, you can download and run the tool, select the files and folders you want to modify, and then use the "Change Time / Attributes" option from the "File" menu. From there, you can modify the creation time of the selected files and folders.

Answer (score 3):

I have researched a lot about this.
I settled with **Copy Handler**:
https://www.copyhandler.com/

It's open source - free.

Initially I used **TeraCopy** (I even have a license for it).
However, since I cannot control TeraCopy's read/write speed (which they said is always at MAXIMUM),
I was worried about wear and tear (especially with HDD).
**(I have a 2TB external HDD that died while transferring files with TeraCopy.)**

**Copy Handler** has A LOT of settings though, and uh... I'm sorry I forgot which setting lets you copy/move the original Date/Time Modified of any file OR folder.

Test **Copy Handler** with temporary files and folders first:

1. Play with the settings.
2. Create a new folder. (Create a new text file to test too.)
3. After a few seconds or a minute, copy or move it.
4. See if the original date/time "created/modified" are retained.

*edited: mentioned it's free.*

Comment: Unlike SSD's, HDD's cannot die by transferring files. If it died, it was already defective. SSD's die when there are to many interruptions causing block clear calls in excess to actual writes; this happens when shaping speeds below that the cache can alleviate.
Thank's for mentioning the software.

Comment: Copy handler seems to be discontinued - "Current stable version: 1.46 (released: 2020-12-24)"

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities for copying an entire partition that are preserve everything and are much faster than any copy program using the filesystem. Search for
windows clone partition